# deploying django to heroku :page not found error

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli, django-deployment

```
I have been making a django app, and am now trying to deploy it to heroku. However when I go on it,says page not found 
the resources not found on the server
```

and i am trying it on different app error remains same
Here is my settings.py (at learst the relevant parts, but please ask if you would like the rest):
"""
Django settings for django_deployment project.

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os 
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['django-deployment85.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_deployment.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_deployment.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

#STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE =  'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
django_heroku.settings(locals())



#and here is my requirement.txt 
asgiref==3.4.1
backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.1
certifi==2021.10.8
distlib==0.3.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
filelock==3.4.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
pipenv==2021.11.23
platformdirs==2.4.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
python-decouple==3.6
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2021.5
virtualenv==20.10.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.7
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.6
waitress==2.0.0
whitenoise==6.0.0
```

Also, when I run the app locally with  python manage.py runserver it works fine, it only doesn't work when I use heroku.

Please tell me if you need anymore information.

Comment: Heroku does not work with [SQLite](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3).  You need to change your database to use [postgres](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes).

Comment: it is connected ,check requirement.txt (psycopg2==2.9.3) and in heroku website it also shows DATABASE_URL=postgres://..........

Answer (score 0):

You may have postgres in Heroku, but your settings.py shows that you are still using SQLite.  The DATABASES section should look like:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'database_name_goes_here',
        'USER': 'username_goes_here',
        'PASSWORD': 'password_goes_here',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

The database name, user, and password you can get by going to your database, then click settings, then credentials.

There are several steps to deploying Django on Heroku.  Configuring Postgres is just one.  There's a nice tutorial at https://dev.to/giftedstan/heroku-how-to-deploy-a-django-app-with-postgres-in-5-minutes-5lk.